# Need help posting username to another form

Tags: c#

I currently have 2 forms, default.aspx ( for registering for an event) , 2nd one userinfo.aspx (To display user's info after registering)

I'm having trouble posting data to the 2nd form and executing a statement

select all from registered when username = username;

I'm sorry if this is an easy thing or the answer is on the internet, I've tried. but i'm a dotnet noob.

```
Code that I need help with : 
 https://pastebin.com/xTLF9hMk
Full Context : 
 https://pastebin.com/HrsF2US0
```

code i need help with

```
default.aspx :  
   <asp:Button Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="RegisterUser"  postbackurl="userinfo.aspx"/>
```

```
default.aspx.cs :  
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["username"] = txtUsername.Text;
        Response.Redirect("userinfo.aspx", false);

    }
```

```
userinfo.aspx.cs :
string a = Session["username"].ToString();
scmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM registered where username = @a";
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question – we don't like jumping through hoops to Pastebin to try and help you. :)

Comment: What problem you are facing with `string a = Session["username"].ToString();` ?

Comment: I'm getting system.nullreferenceException 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState.this[string].get returned null.


@AKX I've inclded the code.

Comment: The error you are getting implies that the `username` is not set in the `Session`. Are you sure you binded the click event to your button so the code setting the variable is being executed?

Comment: I've binded the button, I'm not sure why is the data not being pulled from the first page. 









`private void Button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["username"] = txtUsername.Text;
        Response.Redirect("userinfo.aspx", false);
        
    }`

Comment: You may add a tag to indicate which version of Asp you're using. It'll help people to answer your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually you are doing this

```
string a = Session["username"].ToString();
scmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM registered where username = @a";
```

also add

```
scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a",a);
```

Comment: Thank you so much , my answer is solved. I also need to add a null check for my session to remove the exception.